# The react build is able to show only the beginning page but not other pages in project

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I recently started working with react and built an application in it.

Coming to the problem, my project has multiple pages in it and works fine in the **localhost**. But, when I created an **Build** for my project. I am only to see first page in the application and unable to see the other pages in the project.

For Example:

http://website.com/**login**. I can access this page, as this is the beginning page of the project.

Now, when I switch to another pages. http://website.com/**home**. I am not able to **see the other pages**. It just says that the page is not found.

The below code is the **router file**

```js
import React from 'react';
import {Route, Switch} from 'react-router-dom';
import Layout from '../Layout/index';
import Wrapper from '../App/Wrapper'

import Home from '../HomeDashboard/index'
import History from '../HistoryPage/index'
import Weather from '../Weather/index'

const wrappedRoutes = () => (
    <div>
        <Layout/>
        <div className="container__wrap">
            <Route exact path="/home" component={Home}/>
            <Route exact path="/history" component={History}/>
            <Route exact path="/weather" component={Weather}/>
        </div>
    </div>
);

const Router = () => (
    <Wrapper>
        <main>
            <Switch>
                <Route exact path="/" component={Login}/>
                <Route exact path="/login" component={Login}/>
                <Route path="/" component={wrappedRoutes}/>
            </Switch>
        </main>
    </Wrapper>
);

export default Router;
```

In the **package.json**, I have also created the homepage.

```js
    "homepage": "http://my-website.com",
```

The below is the **index.html** file of the build.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <link href="favicon.ico" rel="shortcut icon"/>
    <meta content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1" name="viewport"/>
    <meta content="#000000" name="theme-color"/>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100,300,400,500,700,900"
          rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://cdn.linearicons.com/free/1.0.0/icon-font.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="./static/css/main.d2ba04f3.chunk.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="manifest.json" rel="manifest"/>
    <title>Enimo</title>
    <link href="./static/css/2.22a7d4ef.chunk.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
<noscript>You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.</noscript>
<div id="root"></div>
<script>!function (l) {
    function e(e) {
        for (var r, n, t = e[0], o = e[1], u = e[2], i = 0, f = []; i < t.length; i++) n = t[i], p[n] && f.push(p[n][0]), p[n] = 0;
        for (r in o) Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(o, r) && (l[r] = o[r]);
        for (s && s(e); f.length;) f.shift()();
        return c.push.apply(c, u || []), a()
    }

    function a() {
        for (var e, r = 0; r < c.length; r++) {
            for (var n = c[r], t = !0, o = 1; o < n.length; o++) {
                var u = n[o];
                0 !== p[u] && (t = !1)
            }
            t && (c.splice(r--, 1), e = i(i.s = n[0]))
        }
        return e
    }

    var n = {}, p = {1: 0}, c = [];

    function i(e) {
        if (n[e]) return n[e].exports;
        var r = n[e] = {i: e, l: !1, exports: {}};
        return l[e].call(r.exports, r, r.exports, i), r.l = !0, r.exports
    }

    i.m = l, i.c = n, i.d = function (e, r, n) {
        i.o(e, r) || Object.defineProperty(e, r, {enumerable: !0, get: n})
    }, i.r = function (e) {
        "undefined" != typeof Symbol && Symbol.toStringTag && Object.defineProperty(e, Symbol.toStringTag, {value: "Module"}), Object.defineProperty(e, "__esModule", {value: !0})
    }, i.t = function (r, e) {
        if (1 & e && (r = i(r)), 8 & e) return r;
        if (4 & e && "object" == typeof r && r && r.__esModule) return r;
        var n = Object.create(null);
        if (i.r(n), Object.defineProperty(n, "default", {
            enumerable: !0,
            value: r
        }), 2 & e && "string" != typeof r) for (var t in r) i.d(n, t, function (e) {
            return r[e]
        }.bind(null, t));
        return n
    }, i.n = function (e) {
        var r = e && e.__esModule ? function () {
            return e.default
        } : function () {
            return e
        };
        return i.d(r, "a", r), r
    }, i.o = function (e, r) {
        return Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(e, r)
    }, i.p = "/";
    var r = window.webpackJsonp = window.webpackJsonp || [], t = r.push.bind(r);
    r.push = e, r = r.slice();
    for (var o = 0; o < r.length; o++) e(r[o]);
    var s = t;
    a()
}([])</script>
<script src="./static/js/2.92847c53.chunk.js"></script>
<script src="./static/js/main.d914cf10.chunk.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

#### **Update:**

I didn't set up the router well and the project was ejected and that caused too many issues with the routing.

Comment: you will need to provide the relevant code.

Comment: I just created a build and I am not able to switch from the beginning page to other page.

Comment: understood, however nobody can help you without looking at the code to see where the issue is.

Comment: maybe start by posting your server, router, and the corresponding components. the relevant stuff.

Comment: I have added the code for the reference. Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually in React when using a client side router you need to tell your server to redirect all the trafic to the /index.html page.

Now you're trying to load pages from the server that are only known by your client's router.

This is a wild guess since you didn't provide any code, but in most cases this is the issue

Comment: Hey @milenko,  thanks for responding. I have added the code to the question, can you please check it. Thank you